# Partial template specialization based on "signed-ness" of integer type?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Given:

```
template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n ) {
  return n >= 0 && n <= 100;
}
```

When used with an `unsigned` type generates a warning:

```
unsigned n;
f( n ); // warning: comparison n >= 0 is always true
```

Is there any clever way not to do the comparison `n >= 0` when `T` is an `unsigned` type?  I tried adding a partial template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
inline bool f( unsigned T n ) {
  return n <= 100;
}
```

but gcc 4.2.1 doesn't like that.  (I didn't think *that* kind of partial template specialization would be legal anyway.)

Comment: Note that there is no partial specialization for function templates, only full specialization.  That said, full specialization is usually a bad idea for function templates because the rules regarding what gets specialized, what gets overloaded, and how overload resolution decides what to use are complicated and convoluted.  Thankfully, overloading and SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error) are sufficient here.

Comment: I get no warning from Clang 3.8 (or GCC 8.0) on this. If I remove the template on `f` I get it though. Is there a version of `-Wtautological-compare` which considers template instantiations?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `enable_if` with the `is_unsigned` type trait:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, bool>::type f(T n)
{
    return n <= 100;  
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<T>::value, bool>::type f(T n)
{
    return n >= 0 && n <= 100;  
}
```

You can find `enable_if` and `is_unsigned` in the `std` or `std::tr1` namespaces if your compiler supports C++0x or TR1, respectively.  Otherwise, Boost has an implementation of the type traits library, [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html).  The boost implementation of `enable_if` is a little different; `boost::enable_if_c` is similar to the TR1 and C++0x `enable_if`.

Comment: Why does it work only with the return type, and not with the argument (which it is about, and would find it more logical), like: `template <typename T>
bool (typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, T>::type n)`

Answer (score 16):

You can take advantage of the wrap-around behavior of unsigned integers.

```
template<bool> struct bool_ { };

template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n, bool_<false> ) {
  return n >= 0 && n <= 100;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n, bool_<true> ) {
  return n <= 100;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n ) {
  return f(n, bool_<(static_cast<T>(-1) > 0)>());
}
```

It's important not to say `>= 0`, to avoid a warning again. The following appears to trick GCC too

```
template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n ) {
  return (n == 0 || n > 0) && n <= 100;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Starting in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with the introduction of [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) you don't even need to provide specializations for this.  Unlike a normal if statement the code in the `if constexpr` will be discarded (not compiled) if the expression is not true.  That means you can rewrite your function like

```
template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n ) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<T>)
        return n <= 100;
    else
        return n >= 0 && n <= 100;
}
```

Comment: `if constexpr` is the great template programming simplifier.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any clever way not to do the comparison n >= 0 when T is an unsigned type? I tried adding a partial template specialization:

The optimizer should drop the code for the compare since it detected the condition.

For Clang, add `-Wno-tautological-compare` to squash the warning. For GCC/G++, add `-Wno-type-limits` to squash the warning.

If you are using a compiler that support `pragma diagnostic {push|pop}` you can:

```cxx
#if (GCC_VERSION >= 40600) || (LLVM_CLANG_VERSION >= 10700) || (APPLE_CLANG_VERSION >= 20000)
# define GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AVAILABLE 1
#endif    

#if MSC_VERSION
# pragma warning(push)
# pragma warning(disable: 4389)
#endif

#if GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AVAILABLE
# pragma GCC diagnostic push
# pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare"
# if (LLVM_CLANG_VERSION >= 20800) || (APPLE_CLANG_VERSION >= 30000)
#  pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-compare"
# elif (GCC_VERSION >= 40300)
#  pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
# endif
#endif

template<typename T>
inline bool f( T n ) {
  return n >= 0 && n <= 100;
}

#if GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AVAILABLE
# pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif

#if MSC_VERSION
# pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

Also see [Comparison is always false due to limited range…](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2056996/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a special template function implementation for `unsigned` type like:

```
template<class T> bool f(T val);
template<> bool f<unsigned>(unsigned val);
```

**UPDATE Unsigned flag**

You can implement different implementations for all unsigned types you'd like to use or add a `bool` flag like:

```
template <class T, bool U> bool f(T val)
{
        if (U)
                return val <= 100;
        else
                return (val >=0 ) && (val <= 100);
}

...

cout << f<int, false>(1) << endl;
cout << f<int, false>(-1) << endl;
cout << f<char, true>(10) << endl;
```

Comment: Except it has to work for all unsigned types: char, short, int, long.

Comment: Your solution is a lot more verbose that the others that take advantage of "enable_if" (or similar functionality).

Comment: Your solution also seems to be the only one that can be implemented in C++03, without using boost. That is a clear plus in my book.
I'll upvote when I get it to work ;)