# Extract signed-ness of template type?

Tags: c++, templates, unsigned, signed

The code below generates a warning with `-Wsign-conversion`. It generates the warning at the line `T digit = a % base`.

I want to extract the signed-ness of `T` and then cast `base` to that signed-ness to squash the warning.

I'm trying to avoid specializations because that just duplicates code (the only thing that's going to change is the signed-ness of `base`). I'm also trying to avoid casting `base` to a `T` in case its a non-POD type like a `Integer` (which is optimized for the reduction with `longs`).

How do I extract the signed-ness of `T`?

---

Related, the code base is effectively C++98 and C++03, so it does not have some features (like discussed in [Partial template specialization based on “signed-ness” of integer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4762110)).

---

```
template <class T>
std::string IntToString(T a, unsigned int base = 10)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return "0";
    bool negate = false;
    if (a < 0)
    {
        negate = true;
        a = 0-a;    // VC .NET does not like -a
    }
    std::string result;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        T digit = a % base;
        result = char((digit < 10 ? '0' : ('a' - 10)) + digit) + result;
        a /= base;
    }
    if (negate)
        result = "-" + result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In your case, it is `a` which should be converted to `unsigned`. (and it would fix edge case (`IntToString<signed char>(-128)`).

Comment: The C++11 type traits library comes from boost. I strongly suggest to use the Boost.TypeTraits library in C++98/03, rather than roll out your own metafunctions.

Comment: @sbabbi - The library uses C++03, and does not have external dependencies. Also, Boost cannot pass acceptance testing. Finally, Boost does not work with the certain Windows-based configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-C++11 you can use this implementation of `std::conditional`:

```
template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };
template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

Then we can write a struct to extract the signedness of a type:

```
template <typename T>
struct signedness {
    typedef typename conditional<T(-1)<T(0),int,unsigned>::type type;   
};
```

Then just declare `base` as being that type:

```
std::string IntToString(T a, 
    typename signedness<T>::type base = 10){
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm on modern GCC and Clang. Next is a round of testing with OpenBSD and Visual Studio (cross-platform libraries can be a pain at times).

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a type is signed using the [`is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) funtcion, and whether it is unsigned using the [`is_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned) function.

To convert a type to the corresponding signed version use [`make_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_signed) and to the corresponding unsigned vesrion use [`make_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned).

Sorry, did not read the C++98 part until now.

Comment: Thanks, but I stated C++98 and C++03.

Answer (score 0):

The signedness of T can be deduced as `std::is_signed<T>::value` as from 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed

Give a look also to the entire [type support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) library for eventual other similar functions about static properties of types.

The type for `base` shuld be

```
std::conditional<std::is_signed<T>::value, int, unsigned>::type
```

Comment: Thanks, but I stated C++98 and C++03.

Comment: @jww you could implement those metafunctions yourself. There are a bunch of implementations online.

Comment: @TartanLlama Whoops, I confused you with the guy who wrote the answer. Sorry.