# Get rid of warning in templated method due to unsignedness

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-warnings, c++03

I have found some templated code which at some point performs the following check:

```
template<class IntegralType>
void randomFunction(IntegralType t)
{
    ...
    if (t < 0)
    ...
}
```

The idea of the code is that `t` is of an integral type (either signed or unsigned). The code works just fine regardless of signedness, but the compiler issues a warning because in the case of an `unsigned` integer the check will always be true.

Is there a way **in C++03** of modifying the code to get rid of the warning without suppressing it? I was thinking of checking the signedness of `T` somehow, don't know it it's possible.

I am aware of C++11's `is_signed` but I am not sure how it could be implemented in C++03.

Comment: You could always use *specialization* for an `unsigned IntegralType`, which doesn't do the comparison and calls one or more functions for the otherwise common code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How would that look? `template<class IntegralType> void randomFunction(unsigned IntegralType)` interprets `unsigned` as `unsigned int` and complains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison is always false due to limited range ... with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056996/comparison-is-always-false-due-to-limited-range-with-templates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Tag dispatching and traits:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_negative(T t, std::true_type)
{
    return t < 0;
}
template <typename T>
bool is_negative(T t, std::false_type)
{
    return false;
}

template<class IntegralType>
void randomFunction(IntegralType t)
{
    ...
    if (is_negative(t, std::is_signed<IntegralType>::type())
    ...
}
```

`std::is_signed` can be implemented in C++03.

Comment: Shouldn't IntegralType be T or T be IntegralType in randomFunction?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 has `is_signed` and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) shows this as possible implementation:

```
namespace detail {
template<typename T,bool = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>
struct is_signed : std::integral_constant<bool, T(-1) < T(0)> {};

template<typename T>
struct is_signed<T,false> : std::false_type {};
} // namespace detail

template<typename T>
struct is_signed : detail::is_signed<T>::type {};
```

The problem is that `is_integral_constant` is only available in C++11 too, however, this might a starting point for you to implement the same in C++03.

Comment: `integral_constant` is almost trivial to backport to C++03 anyway, as it is a purely library solution. Code from an early C++11 compiler's include files for `integral_constant` and all the basic type traits should compile as-is in C++03.

Comment: Does anyone know if this works on OSX, like versions 10.8 and 10.9? Apple provides an unusual C++ std library at times.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution for this problem for some time.

The best solution I've found was using the same idea as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762139/3914029):

```
    if (!(t == 0 || t > 0))
```

which it may be a compiler-specific workaround but at least in g++ 4.4.7 the warning fades away.